# Start Upload all in jquery file upload blueimp

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I use  jQuery file upload blueimp and have read

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        },
        add:function (e, data) {
            $("#uploadBtn").off('click').on('click',function () {
                data.submit();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but this uploads a single file, I want to upload all files that have been selected.

Comment: whats your form code mainly the input section have you set this to <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple> have you also looked at their API details?

Comment: I have read API but not understand, because english bad... please

Comment: did you achievied how to solve your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your problem is that you unbind the click event on every file. you should do it on done:

```
done: function (e, data) {
            $("#uploadBtn").off('click')
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        },
add: function (e, data) {
            $("#uploadBtn").on('click',function () {
                data.submit();
            });
        }
```

Comment: The "point" here is that calling data.submit() on a single file will upload that one file, by calling data.submit() on *all* the files from one button (#uploadBtn) it will add them all to the queue and upload them in turn.

Answer (score 10):

```
var pendingList: [];

var sendAll: function () {
        pendingList.forEach(function (data) { data.submit(); });
        pendingList = [];
    };

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'url_path',
    autoUpload: false,

    add: function (e, data) {
            pendingList.push(data);
        },


});

<button onclick="sendAll()">Start Upload All</button>
```

Comment: That's the only way I can see how to do it. And it works.

Answer (score 1):

For upload concurrently all file you have selected, you can add the option autoUpload: true, like this:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'url_path',
    autoUpload: true
})
```

Reference: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Comment: This answer is wrong, the `autoUpload` option triggers the upload when the file is selected. The question is about uploading more than one file at a button press.