# 403 Forbidden nginx when use method GET ajax

Tags: php, get

I'm doing a an ajax request to the following path:

```
http://example.com/dir/ajax/index.php
http://example.com/dir/ajax/index.php=123
```

that works. But when I'm calling 
`http://example.com/dir/ajax/index.php=http://example.net/` the request is answered withan error `403 forbidden`,

Whats wrong with this call?

Comment: 1. make a proper url: `http://example.com/dir/ajax/index.php?http://example.net/` Use `urlencode` on the embedded url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL seems to be malformed. Have a look at the typical structure of a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure). You're not specifying the name of the query parameter to be parsed by the server. A sample of a valid URL would be

```
http://example.com/dir/ajax/index.php?query_name=http://example.net/
```

or even

```
http://example.com/dir/ajax/index.php?http://example.net/
```

If you're interested in more details about query strings, you should have a look at the standards

- URI: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4
- HTTP: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html

I think in your case you don't have to distinguish between these two standards. If you're interested in building a query string automatically from javascript, have a look at this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript).

Comment: Tks you for reply,
But ago on vps old, this very good..
I think my vhost or nginx config error.

Comment: If you find out, what the error was, please post it as an answer. And please accept answers to your questions if they are solved. See your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740426/start-upload-all-in-jquery-file-upload-blueimp